# Как мне сделать задержку, чтобы пока звук играет, я не мог переключиться на следующие действия программы sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

У меня есть звук который длится 4 секунды. нужно сделать в основном теле программы, сразу после этого кода, так, чтобы я не мог отобразить следующие спрайты, пока звук не закончится. Или же как-то ставить таймер. Я новичок в sfml, надеюсь понятно объяснил.

```
SoundBuffer loadlobbyprojector;//создаём буфер для звука
    loadlobbyprojector.loadFromFile("KDS-1/loadgamegui/music/loadlobbyprojector.ogg");//загружаем в него звук
    Sound projector(loadlobbyprojector);//создаем звук и загружаем в него звук из буфера
    projector.play();
```

Comment: Задержки не нужны. Сохраняйте где-то время, после которого можно будет продолжать действия, и при каждом обновлении игрового состояния проверяйте, не настало ли это время.

Comment: можно в цикле обработки собщений проверять `sf::Sound::getStatus()`